# Sum up the elements of a record

Tags: sum, ocaml, record

```
type MyType = {a:int; b:int};;
let test = [{a=5;b=10}; {a=10;b=100}; {a=200; b=500}; {a=100; b=2}];;
```

I would like to create a function which will sum up `a` and `b` in such a way it will display

```
Sum of a : 315
Sum of b : 612
```

I think I have to use a recursive function. Here is my attempt :

```
let my_func record =
  let adds = [] in 
  let rec add_func = match adds with
  | [] -> record.a::adds; record.b::adds
  | _ -> s + add_func(e::r)

add_func test;;
```

This function doesn't seem to work at all. Is there a right way to do such function?

Comment: What type is the parameter of `my_func`? You are naming it `s`. If I understand correctly, `my_func` should process a list of of records (such as the value `test`), but in the body of `my_func` you are treating `s` as a single record (so you have expressions `s.a` and `s.b`).

Comment: You need to know how to process a list of things. Then it will be much easier to see how to keep two running sums as you process your list of records. So I propose you write a function that just adds up all the numbers in a list of ints.

Comment: StackOverflow is not good for this, unfortunately. You can look up my email and write me. I honestly expect that if you can write a recursive function to add the numbers in a list, you'll see how to solve your problem. You're right that the idiomatic way to do it would be to use a fold, but what would a specially written recursive function look like? (Also you can use fold to solve your problem with records btw.)

Comment: @JeffreyScofield I know how to sum a list of integer for instance, i.e. `let rec sum = function  | [] -> 0 | h::t -> h + (sum t)`. My problem is probably how to deal with list of records. I don't know sum up the a's and the b's in the same time.

Comment: OK, I will make an answer that gives the basic idea. The formatting the comments is too crude.

Comment: @chessguy Are python answers okay?

Answer (score 1):

OK, you know exactly what you're doing, you just need one suggestion I think.

Assume your function is named `sumab` and returns a pair of ints. Then the key expression in your recursive function will be something like this:

```
| { a = ha; b = hb; } :: t ->
    let (a, b) = sumab t in (ha + a, hb + b)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be accomplished quite concisely with `List.fold_left` which is applicable anywhere you want to convert a list to some other value.

```
let my_func lst =
  let add {a=a1; b=b1} {a=a2; b=b2} = 
    {a=a1+a2; b=b1+b2} 
  in
  let zero = {a=0; b=0} in
  List.fold_left add zero lst
```

For your `test` variable, evaluation would look like:

```
my_func [{a=5;b=10}; {a=10;b=100}; {a=200; b=500}; {a=100; b=2}]
List.fold_left add zero [{a=5;b=10}; {a=10;b=100}; {a=200; b=500}; {a=100; b=2}]
List.fold_left add {a=5; b=10} [{a=10;b=100}; {a=200; b=500}; {a=100; b=2}]
List.fold_left add {a=15; b=110} [{a=200; b=500}; {a=100; b=2}]
List.fold_left add {a=215; b=610} [{a=100; b=2}]
List.fold_left add {a=315; b=612} []
{a=315; b=612}
```